# 2 websites 2 domain 1 installation

Tags: magento2.2, websites, multidomain

I'm setting up a pretty complex site with a lot of API handling. Now that site needs to have 1 installation and 2 websites on 2 domains. I'm not sure how this works with Magento.

**What i have now**

So have i created my 2 websites within Magento and i have adjusted each website to have a different base and secure url. Lets say domain 1 is domain1.com and domain2 is domain2.com.

I also have the 2 domains forwarded over A records to the same IP from the installation. So lets say the IP for example is 55.55.55.55 then i have both domains (domain1.com and domain2.com) set up to navigate to 55.55.55.55.

Now when i surf to this domain1.com i get to see domain1.com. When i surf to domain2.com (that i added later in the installation) it seems to still redirect to domain1.com

My question , how would one set this up?

Answer (score 0):

Did you start with http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html 
Documentation describes quite clearly how to set up multiple websites with both Nginx and Apache.

Comment: I'm using a webhost so i can not access the Apache on the server. Isn't there another way?

Comment: You can use [.htaccess file](https://www.cloudways.com/blog/create-and-configure-multistore-magento-2/)

Comment: I'm changing host anyways. Magento is not made for a shared hosting